# Getting a compilation error when I try and access ViewData through JS

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-2

```
ViewData["results"] = indication.Model.prepaymentList;
return View(@"~\Views\Indications\TermSheetViews\Swap\PrePayment.aspx", indication.Model);
```

This works fine but my compilation error is happening on the view on this line:

```
var prepaymentList = <%= ViewData["results"]; %>;
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many `;`. It should be:

```
var prepaymentList = <%= ViewData["results"] %>;
```

Of course writing something like this makes absolutely no sense whatsoever.

You probably need:

```
var prepaymentList = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["results"]) %>;
```

Which of course leads to another problem which is the usage of `ViewData`. I would recommend you using a strongly typed view and model so that finally you have:

```
var prepaymentList = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
```

Comment: If ViewData contains javascript literal than it makes sense ;-)

Comment: @Jakub Konecki, ViewData comes from a controller. Do you really intend putting javascript literals inside a controller???????? That makes even less sense. A controller works with a repository and pass a view model to a view for rendering, full stop. Javascript belongs inside a view.

Comment: No need to use that many question marks in response to a smiley... ;)

Answer (score 0):

A quick guess: try removing `;` after `]`